# Maven Build Failure - Plugin Resolution Error

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I am having an issue while building one of the maven project. The error is as below.

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: 3 problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
[ERROR] [ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6, must be "pom" but is "maven-plugin" @
[ERROR] [ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6, must be "pom" but is "maven-plugin" @
[ERROR] [FATAL] The parents form a cycle: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 -> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 @
```

But this points to maven resources plugin and the packaging for this particular artifact is maven-plugin in central repo. Can someone suggest how this can be resolved locally?

Please find the POM below. I have taken out other dependencies and maintained only the relevant part.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>copr.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>dp-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DP ParentPOM</name>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Corp_Tech_Artifactory01-releases</name>
            <url>https://www-repo.com/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot</name>
            <url>https://www-repo.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <revision>SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.release.plugin.version>2.5.3</maven.release.plugin.version>

        <spring.core.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.core.version>


    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- override abstract method in PAM security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.ws.core.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.5</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- added dependency to avoid jibx-java8 compatibility issues -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
                            <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
                            <version>6.0</version>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <encoding>cp1252</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>auk.corp.demgmt</groupId>
                            <artifactId>codemetrics</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.h3xstream.findsecbugs</groupId>
                            <artifactId>findsecbugs-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>auk.corp.demgmt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>codemetrics</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>cp1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: show us your pom

Comment: Looks like you defined `maven-resources-plugin` in the `dependencies` section instead of the `plugins` section.

Comment: @ XtremeBaumer Please find the pom updated in the original post.

Comment: @Aaron If you look at the pom, resources plugin is updated under plugins section.

Comment: Solution was to delete the local repo, somehow its got corrupted.